# "HagGomel" and Sefer Torah

Tags: blessing, sefer-torah, hagomel

The widespread practice seems to say the beracha of HagGomel in the presence of a Sefer Torah. Is this a halacha or a minhag? What is the source for this practice?

Furthermore, what is the relationship between the beracha of HagGomel and a Sefer Torah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Orach Chaim 219:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=267) we make the Bracha of Hagomel in front of a Sefer Torah since there is 10 people there and it is proper to  say the Bracha with a Minyan.

Comment: This seems like a partial answer, to me. Why specifically at Torah reading? Why not say it after Kaddish is said?