# Ha-Gommel before or after Kaddish?

Tags: blessing, torah-reading, kaddish, hefsek-interruption

If the one reading from the Torah (whether it be on Mondays, Thursday, Shabbos, etc) has to say the bracha of "Ha-Gommel" when should it be recited? Is it ok to say it after the last aliyah *before* he recites Kaddish. Or perhaps this is an interruption ("hefsek") and should be said after the one reading from the Torah ("bal koreh") says Kaddish?

Comment: Are you asking only according to the custom that each _ole_ reads? If not, why ask only about the reader [who, I assume you mean, happens to be the final _ole_] and not any other final _ole_?

Comment: @msh210 Because of the question of "hefsek" is better to ask between the oleh finishing the bracha and then the bal koreh reciting kaddish to finish off the reading rather then the oleh making the bracha and then still having to call up another oleh.

Comment: @msh210 or I could answer your question by saying I'm asking the way I am, because that's my question! Exactly in that case. If you have a question feel free to ask it

Comment: I understood why you were asking about the last _ole_ and not a previous one: the question is about a _hefsek_ before _kadish_. I didn't (and don't) understand why you were asking only about the case that the reader happens to be that last _ole_. Seems a very restrictive and unusual case: that someone should be the last _ole_, be the _kore_, and need to say "_Hagomel_". At least among _Ashk'nazim_. If that's the case you're asking about, then editing your motivation into your question would vastly improve it.

Comment: Interesting I was at Chabad House one Shabbos and the person after his aliya started to say Hagomel incl Hashem name and the Rabbi cut him short and said to the bal koreh to say the Kaddish. The rabbi asked the person who received the aliya to say Baruch Shem... and then after Kaddish say hagomel.

Answer (score 6):

This is discussed in Chakirey Minhagim (Rabbi Eliyahu Yochonan Gurary, vol. 2 pg. 90):

Eshel Avraham (OC 219:3) debated this and although he begins by saying that it would seem to be a interruption to say Hagomel between the brochos and kadish, he concludes that where there is no existing custom it is perhaps preferable to say Hagomel first. His explanation (as far as I understand) is that it is fitting to say Kadish after thanking Hashem for His kindness.

However the Shu"t Yerach Yaakov ([Siman 40](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1063&pgnum=202)) writes at length that one should say Hagomel only after Kadish, and this is still considered fulfilling the minhag (see [Tosfos Brochos 54b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=54b&format=pdf)) of reciting Hagomel at the time of Kriyas Hatorah. Similarly Rabbi Betzalel Stern (Ohalalecha Be'amisecha 23:61) writes that it would seem that Hagomel should only be said after Kadish.

The prevalent custom is to to say Hagomel before Kadish (as Rabbi Stern notes). The Chabad custom however is to say Hagomel after Kadish ([Sefer Haminhagim Chabad](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/14.htm)). See also Shaar Ephraim (Shaar 10, sec. 9)

Comment: see also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15736/759

Comment: Hahaha I searched hebrewbooks for ירח יעקב! that was silly of me